# Mixin using @extend_schema (drf_spectacular) using instance serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

I want to set the responses for @extend_schema dynamically.
The Mixin is inherited by different Subclasses, their response can vary depending on their Serializer. Therefore I would like to have the responses be set dynamically. Is that possible?

```
class Mixin:
    @extend_schema(
        request=None,
        responses={
            status.HTTP_200_OK: self.__class__.get_serializer(), # <--- self obviously won't work
            status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT: None,
        }
    )
    @action(detail=True, methods=['post'], url_path='decline')
    def decline(self, request, **kwargs):
        # do something
```

I tried to patch the viewset and write a function selecting the serializer dynamically, but it always boils down to the point, that the responses are set in a static context which made me wonder if it is even possible to set it dynamically?